# select count does not return the actual total of records inside the sql table

Tags: sql

I want to count the total number of records inside the sql table but the codes returning different value for example the records that exist in the table is 14 but its returning 1.
Here is my code:

```
            DBConn dbConn = new DBConn();
            SqlConnection connObj = dbConn.getConnObj();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from dbo.[tbl_users]");
            SqlDataAdapter ap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText,connObj);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            connObj.Open();
            ap.Fill(ds);
            lbltotal.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();
            connObj.Close();
```

Can someone point me where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: I think you are trying to get the number of records returned from the select query. It will always be 1. You need to get the value of the 1st record returned in the resultset.

Comment: Are you sure you're verifying the same database? You query should return the n° of records!

Answer (score 1):

Yes `Row.Count` will return 1 because the `count` values is returned in `Dataset` with single row.

So you are geting row count as 1

Try this

```
DBConn dbConn = new DBConn();
SqlConnection connObj = dbConn.getConnObj();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from dbo.[tbl_users]",connObj);
connObj.Open();
lbltotal.Text = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
connObj.Close();
```

**Or**

Try this

```
DBConn dbConn = new DBConn();
SqlConnection connObj = dbConn.getConnObj();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count (*) from dbo.[tbl_users]");
SqlDataAdapter ap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText,connObj);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

connObj.Open();
ap.Fill(ds);
lbltotal.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString();
connObj.Close();
```

Comment: Hai,I try it but it giving me this error Compiler Error Message: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The second one only return 1 instead of the actual number of records in the table